# i want to get price from invo where rows = column(main) in datagrideview

Tags: c#

I'd like to get price from invo where

```
rows = column(main)
```

I use these code to fill price in `dgRow.Cells[5].Value`

When I click the button I have one record

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgRow in dgw.Rows)
            {
                string name = dgRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                con.Close();
                con.Open();
                cmd = con.CreateCommand();

                cmd.CommandText = "select price from  invo where main='"+name+"' '";
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    if (rdr.IsDBNull(0))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dgRow.Cells[5].Value = (rdr.GetDecimal(0).ToString());
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You only have 1 record because you do a `return` after the first record.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code should like this :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgRow in dgw.Rows)
        {
            string name = dgRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            con.Close();
            con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "select price from  invo where main='"+name+"' '";
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr.IsDBNull(0))
                {


                }
                else
                {

                    dgRow.Cells[5].Value = (rdr.GetDecimal(0).ToString());
                    break; //return; Get you out of the function, additional 
                           //rows are not evaluated


                }
            }
        }
```

Using "return" in your while loop get you out of the function thus not processing next rows.